# Visual Studio 2008 V 2005 Where's my Code?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I've been useing VS2005 to create sql reports and now have to upgrade to 2008 for a DB thats on SQL Server 2008. 
With 2005 I can swap between dataset-Layout-Preview easily but with 2008 I can only seem to swap between layout-preview...
Where's my code if I want to edit it as I go along or add datasets etc..

Thanks ion advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the dataset designer panel (its a dockable panel like "Properties" or "Toolbox"). When you open the report in design view and then open the "View" menu, it should be the last item in the menu.

This is where you create your data sets and manage report parameters.

**EDIT**
I'm not sure what the menu item's called in the English version of VS 2008. I did the following now: I opened an existing VS2005 Reporting project in VS 2008 and followed the wizard to convert the project. Then I double-clicked one report in the solution explorer to open the designer. Then I already had a docked window that's called "Berichtsdaten" (Report Data?) in German. I see a menu item in the "View" menu at the bottom called "Berichtsdaten" with a "Ctrl+Alt+D" shortcut (see attached image).

You may have to try different activated elements. For example, the item may not be shown if the "Properties" window is active. Try clicking at some free space in the report designer first.

[image]

Comment: Cant see that option anywhere??